Multiclass arrivals with different service rates but equal priority
I have a 3 class arrival, each having arrival rate $\lambda_i$ and service rate $\mu_i$. I want to know this queue's expected queue length ($L_q$) and queue waiting time ($W_q$). Assume $M/M/1$ behavior.
I know there are many online resources assuming priorities on the classes, but in my case, all these classes have equal priorities. Is there a resource/paper that does that calculations for such a queue?

What happens if in these online resources, you make the priorities equal? Perhaps you can tell us what the most applicable resources you know of are?

We can treat this queue as an M/G/1 with a hyperexponential job size distribution and FCFS service.
Specifically, it is an M/G/1 with arrival rate $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3$, and job size distribution
$$S = \begin{cases}
\operatorname{Exp}(\mu_1) & \rm w.p. \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda} \\
\operatorname{Exp}(\mu_2) & \rm w.p. \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda} \\
\operatorname{Exp}(\mu_3) & \rm w.p. \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda}. \\
\end{cases}$$
Now, we can apply the Pollaczek-Khinchine formula for the mean queueing time and mean queue length of an M/G/1, which states that
$$ W_q = \frac{\lambda E[S^2]}{2(1-\lambda E[S])}, L_q = \lambda W_q.$$
